# Managing Concurrent POST-Requests Best Practice in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, rest, post, http-post

I am building a REST-API with SpringBoot and using this Controller.

```
@RestController
class EmployeeController {

  private final EmployeeRepository repository;

  EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @GetMapping("/employees")
  List<Employee> all() {
    return repository.findAll();
  }

  @PostMapping("/employees")
  Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {
    return repository.save(newEmployee);
  }
```

I want to ensure that API-Consumers cannot spam multiple concurrent POST-Requests with the same `Employee`. I know that I can check if the entity already exists in the database before saving it, but I am afraid that the performance will be bad. I also already noticed that you can use Annotation like `@version` in your entity, to make updates on existing Entity`s more save.

But is there also a way or a best practice in Spring how to handle this POST-Requests with a potential new Entity?

Comment: Checking if the employee exists will not save you as you mentioned. You have to add *rate limiting* to handle requests before even reaching db. Or you have to one version of *locking*. AFAIK there is no other way

Answer (score 0):

What kind of request throughput are you expecting to the `POST /employees` endpoint? While performance is important, premature optimization is almost always going to cause your code to be uglier than it needs to for little gain.

As your code currently stands, multiple concurrent `POST /employees` requests would end up with a first-come first-serve basis where the first user with the given `UNIQUE` constraint in your application (which is hopefully enforced by your underlying DBMS) is created, and all other after that (for the same user) would fail due to a e.g. `ConstraintViolationException` (mapped to a e.g. `DataIntegrityViolationException`). From this point of view (as long as you do not have a complicated distributed DBMS setup), the consistency of the data is still guaranteed.

The downside, of course, is that the error messages that would be returned would be:

1. Vendor-specific and leak the underlying implementation (e.g. we're showing the client that we're using Hibernate)
2. Potentially difficult for the client to parse.

If you instead, change the implementation to something like the following:

```java
  @PostMapping("/employees")
  Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {
    verifyEmployeeDoesNotExist(newEmployee);
    return repository.save(newEmployee);
  }

  private void verifyUserDoesNotExist(Employee employee) {
    if (repository.exists(newEmployee) {
      throw new EmployeeAlreadyExistsException("Employee " + newEmployee.getName() + " already exists";
    }
  }
```

then you could more easily control the control flow of your endpoint and the underlying process, which would potentially allow for more easily-digestible exception handling. This could be even further improved by adding e.g. custom exceptions which also contain some code of pre-defined `error code` such as e.g. `error 409 code 1010 Employee already exists`.

Of course, Spring's built-in exception translation for Hibernate (e.g. `HibernateExceptionTranslator`) might already be good enough for your use-case and could even be extended and this extension can be even generalized.

In the end, the best practice is making your code clean, readable and maintainable. Then start adding functionality to monitor your code. *After that*, and only *if* you have a problem with performance, you can still optimize it.